# Building spark-cassandra-connector: SBT cannot resolve dependencies

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt

I have cloned the [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) in order to fix [one of its unresolved issues](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-653).
Prior to any code changes, I'm trying to build locally, as explained in the [developer guide](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/developers.md).
But whichever SBT command that I run, fails with an unresolved dependency errors:

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api;2.11.1: org.apache#apache;18!apache.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/gcatz/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/18/apache-18.pom
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.11.1: org.apache#apache;18!apache.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/gcatz/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/18/apache-18.pom
[error] unresolved dependency: com.squareup.okhttp3#okhttp;3.7.0: org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7!oss-parent.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/gcatz/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
...
```

I'm using a mac (Monterey), Java 1.8.

I wrote some comments regarding the issue in the [original thread](https://community.datastax.com/questions/11407/spark-cassandra-connector-unable-to-access-materia.html) on DataStax community, but have been asked to open a new thread here instead.

Have you guys ever encountered such an issue with SBT?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62517800/how-to-fix-origin-location-must-be-absolute-error-in-sbt-project-with-spark-2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882265/sbt-new-runtimeexception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111648/origin-location-must-be-absolute-error-in-building-a-sbt-project-intellij this can be a broken cache. Try to delete the cache so that it will be downloaded from the scratch

Comment: Also try fresher sbt. Current sbt is 1.8.0 while the bundled is 1.3.3 (see directory `sbt`, and the project is built with 1.2.8, see `project/build.properties`) https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

Comment: If the issue remains please provide the full log of `sbt clean compile`.

Comment: Thanks @DmytroMitin,

I have removed `~/.ivy2/cache` folder and ran `sbt/sbt clean compile`.
It has successfully downloaded a bunch of dependencies without complaining.
After that, however, the following error has occurred:

`error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/Cannot invoke "scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.typerPhase()" because the return value of "scala.tools.nsc.Global.currentRun()" is null)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI`

Comment: After that, I've downloaded sbt-launch 1.8.0 from (here)[https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.8.0].
I placed that jar next to the existing 1.3.3, changed SBT_VERSION in the sbt script. and ran `sbt/sbt clean compile` again. The result appears to be the same.

Comment: `Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-1.8.0.jar
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
...
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/Cannot invoke "scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.typerPhase()" because the return value of "scala.tools.nsc.Global.currentRun()" is null)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:175)
...`

Comment: There are different versions of sbt. Sbt is a shell script running [sbt-launch.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch) (based on [launcher.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/launcher)), which downloads and runs the rest of sbt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440324/sbt-gives-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-run-spark There is the version of script (currently 1.8.0), version of `sbt-launch.jar` (1.8.0, based on `launcher` 1.4.1), actual version of sbt used for project building (specified in `project/build.properties`).

Comment: You seem to mix older script with fresher launcher. Although this should work I would try to download sbt from https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html, so using fresh `bin/sbt` script with fresh `bin/sbt-launch.jar` running fresh the rest of `sbt` and try to specify fresh sbt in `project/build.properties`.

Comment: Also `/modules/java.base/...` looks like you're using Java 9 (or fresher), not 8. Please execute `which java`, `java -version` to be sure what java is installed in the system and used.

Comment: Many thanks @DmytroMitin!
It appears like the script was taking the wrong version of java after all.
After I put the path to the java 8 installation as the first one in my $PATH, the sbt scripts stopped failing.

Comment: Great! Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was in broken cache (`~/.m2`, `~/.ivy2`). Removing the cache helped with `origin location must be absolute`

[How to fix "origin location must be absolute" error in sbt project (with Spark 2.4.5 and DeltaLake 0.6.1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62517800/how-to-fix-origin-location-must-be-absolute-error-in-sbt-project-with-spark-2)

[sbt new RuntimeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882265/sbt-new-runtimeexception)

[Origin location must be absolute error in building a SBT project, IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111648/origin-location-must-be-absolute-error-in-building-a-sbt-project-intellij)

Also wrong version of Java was selected (Java 9 instead of 8). Correcting `$PATH` helped with `error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken (class java.lang.NullPointerException/Cannot invoke "scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.typerPhase()" because the return value of "scala.tools.nsc.Global.currentRun()" is null) [error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI [error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:175)`